# Aligning text on same line ignoring space from left and right

Tags: php, html, css

my web application is simple: a person enters details in a form, when submitted it comes out this way:

Name: Kyle blah blah    **First**
Name: Josh blah blah   **Referral**

I want it that first and referral are exactly aligned that way, my problem is that if someone enters the name Kyle only, it becomes like this:

Name: Kyle    **First**
Name: Josh blah blah   **Referral**

I don't want that to happen ^.

Here is my code:

```css
div.inline { 
  float:right;
}
.clearBoth { 
  clear:both; 
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">Name:<u>WHATEVERCOMESFROMFORM</u><font style="margin-right: 250px">First</style></div>
<div class="inline">Name:<u>WHATEVERCOMESFROMFORM</u><font style="margin-right: 250px">Refferal</style></div>
```

Any help?

Comment: please create fiddle for reproducing issue, it is very hard to understand the issue

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear. Do you mean you want 'Name Kyle blah blah' on one line and 'First Name: Josh blah blah' on another line and then 'Referral' on a third line?

Comment: @ILoveCSS I meant that Name and Referral should be exactly under each other whatever the length of both names might be. What's happening rn is that if the name length is not equal, referral and name wouldn't be equally under each other.

Comment: @pradeep1991singh ^

Comment: edited my first post. wow i didn't realize it needed editing, thats why none of you guys understood what i meant. @ILoveCSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the old good table tag

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><u>looooooooooooooong Word</u></td>
  <td><u>First</u></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><u>tiny</u></td>
   <td><u>Referral</u></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope that this is what you mean

Comment: I meant that Name and Referral should be exactly under each other whatever the length of both names might be. What's happening rn is that if the name length is not equal, referral and name wouldn't be equally under each other. – Ali 8 secs ago   edit

Comment: be exactly under each other at start and at the end ? like

Ahmed
A   l    i

Comment: I mean you want the smaller word to expand ?

Comment: No not expand, Name and Referal should be under each other thats it.

Comment: edited my first post. wow i didn't realize it needed editing, thats why none of you guys understood what i meant.

Comment: if you can make a fiddle or something cause i'm not understanding you

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```css
div.inline>u {margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  Name:<u>WHATEVERCOMESFROMFORM</u><font style="margin-left: 5px;font-weight:bold;">First</font>
 </div>
 <div class="inline">
  Name:<u>Kyle</u><font style="margin-left: 5px;font-weight:bold;">Refferal</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the layout of the output, comparing:

> Name: Kyle blah blah First Name: Josh blah blah Referral

and

> Name: Kyle First Name: Josh blah blah Referral

the 'First Name' appears more to the left and nearer to 'Name'. Therefore, I'm assuming you're looking for equal widths for each of these three labels, so that they line up vertically, as there is probably numerous rows of data.

In this case you could add a `label` or a `span` tag around 'Name', 'First Name', and 'Referral'. You'd need to careful though, because if someone types some long text, it will wrap over onto the next line. I would use a table. They are designed for this exact purpose - to hold data in an orderly way. And a table will automatically adjust to the available space.

```html
<style>
  td {
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: Kyle blah blah</td>
    <td>First Name: Josh blah blah</td>
    <td>Referral</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: Kyle</td>
    <td>First Name: Josh blah blah</td>
    <td>Referral</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see you have edited your question. The answers to use a 'table' still apply, and would I believe be the best solution. Just use two cells instead of three.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center color: #999;
  color: #999;
}
.ztable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 15px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Really loooong name</th>
      <th>First</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>looong name</th>
      <th>referal</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Short name</th>
      <th>First</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Jack</th>
      <th>referal</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```